# How to take data from Ext.Record?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I can take record from store: `var record = store.getAt(i);`
    But if i want to take fileds which have a same name from record i get only first field value. For example if i have XML with:

```
Code:

<zem>
  <parcel>
    ....
  <parcel>
  <really>
    <price>555.555<price>
  </really>
  <really>
    <price>666.666<price>
  </really>
</zem>
```

And using `record.get("price")` i can get only `555.555` value.
    Its possible to get values of all fields of `<really>`? Or array of values of all fields with name=`<price>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a walk on store:

```
var res = [];
store.each(function(record) { res.push(record.get('price'));  })
```